# You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with ConfigChanges (but I declared it)

Tags: android, admob

I tried

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

and

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

I also declared permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

...but it returns the same error on the app:

> You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with ConfigChanges

Thanks `:)`

*PS: sorry for any error, I'm Italian `:(`*

Comment: Show you full AndroidManifest. Which library are you using to get your Admob classes?

Answer (score 0):

The 1st activity you listed is correct. Do you have the metadata tag?

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Have you added Google Play Services to your build path?

Comment: Isn't GPS incompatible with AdMob?